# return $this->redirect not redirecting to target

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have the following function `subscribe`:

```
public function subscribe() {
    $plans = Configure::read('Stripe.american_plans');
    $plans['premium_american_monthly'] = __('Premium Monthly') . ' - 4.99';
    $plans['premium_american_annually'] = __('Premium Annually') . ' - 49.99';

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));

        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your account has been subscribed'));
            debug($this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'edit']));
            die();
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('User could not be subscribed.');
        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('plans'));
}
```

I do manipulate the $users object before I save it in the actual function, but this is the simplest I can make the function and have the page still load and the error still happen.

The debug statement around the redirect is to check where it's redirecting the user, and that spits out:

```
object(Cake\Http\Response) {

'status' => (int) 302,
'contentType' => 'text/html',
'headers' => [
    'Content-Type' => [
        (int) 0 => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    ],
    'Location' => [
        (int) 0 => 'https://localhost/users/subscribe'
    ]
],
'file' => null,
'fileRange' => [],
'cookies' => [
    'cookies go here'
    ]
],
'cacheDirectives' => [],
'body' => ''

}
```

As you can see it's not redirecting to where I expect it to. In fact, no matter what I put in that redirect statement, it's always redirecting to the same function, `subscribe`.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, as this code looks identical to other functions I have that function properly. Does anyone know how to make this redirect to where I want it to redirect?

Comment: `Controller::redirect()` will only set the `Location` header if it hasn't been set already, so check what `$this->response` looks like. Also note that `Controller.beforeRedirect` can interfere here and modify the response so that `redirect()` won't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ndm for his comment, led me to a solution. It feels like a dirty solution, as I don't think I'm resolving the actual issue, but it does work. Before I redirect I've added the following:

```
$url = Router::url(['controller' => Users', 'action' => 'edit']);
$this->response = $this->response->withLocation($url);
```

The issue was happening because somewhere my headers were already being set with the incorrect location. I'm not sure where this is happening, as none of our other redirect logic was being hit, and we don't implement `beforeRedirect` anywhere within our code.

But, as I said, this works and does solve the problem.

Comment: Without knowing the codebase I'd still bet my money on the `Controller.beforeRedirect` event, it could be a plugin, but who knows. I'd suggest to set breakpoints in `Response::location()`, `Response::withLocation()`, and `MessageTrait::withHeader()` to figure where the change stems from.